# Standalone build failed Expo Execution failed for task ':app:mergeProdKernelReleaseResources'

Tags: android, ios, react-native, expo

My using hd quality 1024x1024 png image but still getting this issue even application is not compile in ios
and giving this error:

**Your application icon can't have transparency if you wish to upload your app to Apple Store.**

I have complete check my application but its fine.

```
> Task :app:mergeProdKernelReleaseResources FAILED
[stderr] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[stderr] * What went wrong:
[stderr] Execution failed for task ':app:mergeProdKernelReleaseResources'.
[stderr] > java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource compilation failed
[stderr]   Output:  /app/turtle/workingdir/android/sdk32/android-shell-app/app/src/main/res/drawable-xxxhdpi/shell_launch_background_image.png: error: failed to read PNG signature: file does not start with PNG signature.
[stderr]   
[stderr]   Command: /root/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-linux.jar/86f0959622145d3be808625a1d88d51d/aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-linux/aapt2 compile --legacy \
[stderr]           -o \
[stderr]           /app/turtle/workingdir/android/sdk32/android-shell-app/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/prodKernel/release \
[stderr]           /app/turtle/workingdir/android/sdk32/android-shell-app/app/src/main/res/drawable-xxxhdpi/shell_launch_background_image.png
[stderr]   Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-linux Daemon #5
[stderr] * Try:
[stderr] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
[stderr] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
[stderr] BUILD FAILED in 29s
17 actionable tasks: 17 executed
Error: ./gradlew exited with non-zero code: 1
    at ChildProcess.completionListener (/app/turtle/node_modules/@expo/xdl/node_modules/@expo/spawn-async/build/spawnAsync.js:52:23)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:317:30)
    at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:915:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
    ...
    at spawnAsync (/app/turtle/node_modules/@expo/xdl/node_modules/@expo/spawn-async/build/spawnAsync.js:17:21)
    at spawnAsyncThrowError (/app/turtle/node_modules/@expo/xdl/build/detach/ExponentTools.js:233:45)
    at buildShellAppAsync (/app/turtle/node_modules/@expo/xdl/build/detach/AndroidShellApp.js:801:11)
    at <anonymous>
```

Comment: check this image `drawable-xxxhdpi/shell_launch_background_image.png`

Comment: upload image here @Muhammad Hamza Nisar

Comment: i didn't found this image in complete project file that is why i'm confused